# how create homescreen shortcut to resume top activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a litlte code to add a shortcut to homescreen for the first running time:

```
    Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            SFlashActivity.class);

    shortcutIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);

    Intent addIntent = new Intent();
    addIntent
            .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "New App");
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,
            Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(),
                    R.drawable.ic_launcher));

    addIntent
            .setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
    addIntent
            .putExtra("duplicate", false);
    getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(addIntent);
```

But with above code, my app always start Splash screen althought my app is running.
So how could i make home screen shortcut resume to top activity.
I noticed that, app's shortcut made by google play on install always resume the top activity.

Thank so much !

Comment: you should store data inside "SharedPreferences" when your application first time starts.

Comment: The standard behaviour is to resume the top activity if your app is already running. You've got something strange going on if this isn't happening. I know you've already accepted an answer, but that answer is overkill and shouldn't be necessary. Add the contents of your manifest to the question. Perhaps there's something nasty in there.

Comment: Also note that there is a bug in Android that will show the behaviour that you described, if the app was initially started from the installer or an IDE (Eclipse, Android Studio, etc). To make sure you aren't seeing this bug: install your app on the device, don't open it by clicking "open" on the installer screen, now go to the home screen and start your app by clicking the app icon. See if your problem has now gone away. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296203/on-click-of-shortcut-on-homescreen-launching-from-spalsh-screen-in-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the isTaskRoot() method 
Enter the following code snippet to your OnCreate() of your main activity 
Here is an example:

---

```
 @Override public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);              
        if(!isTaskRoot()){
            finish();
            return; 
        }
 }
```

Found the solution [here](http://www.jjask.com/363784/avoid-click-android-shortcut-create-instance-and-kill-the-one):

Answer (score 0):

I also went through the same problem of resuming the application while coming back when the app is in background because of the Home button press,

Two changes To be done

1.Add below property to the activities in manifest file

```
android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
```

This will resume the activities when coming from the launcher icon.

2.Upper change wont resume the application if you click on the app icon on Home screen which you have created programatically. Because you have specified the "SFlashActivity.class" for the launching purpose. To overcome this you will have to do a trick as below:

Add this function to your SFlashActivity.class

```
public boolean CheckIfAppIsResumable(){
    try{
         ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
         List<RunningTaskInfo> runningTaskInfoList =  am.getRunningTasks(1);
         Iterator<RunningTaskInfo> itr = runningTaskInfoList.iterator();
         while(itr.hasNext()){
             RunningTaskInfo runningTaskInfo = (RunningTaskInfo)itr.next();
             CharSequence desc= runningTaskInfo.description;
             int numOfActivities = runningTaskInfo.numActivities;
             int numRunning=runningTaskInfo.numRunning;
             String topActivity = runningTaskInfo.topActivity.getClassName();
             Log.d("description", ""+desc);
             Log.d("numActivities", ""+numOfActivities);
             Log.d("numRunning", ""+numRunning);
             Log.d("topActivity", ""+topActivity);
             if(numRunning>1 && topActivity.equalsIgnoreCase("com.yourpackage.yoursplashclass"))
                 return true;
         }
         return false;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.d("Errror CheckIsAppIsResumable=", ""+e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
}
```

And in Oncreate:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(CheckIfAppIsResumable()){
        finish();
        return;//will finish the new started splash activity
    }
```

Provided that your shortcut intent does not have flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP.